# Promote document data to meta-data

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way to "promote" information in a document(Word, Visio, etc) to "meta-data" that can be auto-magically represented in a SharePoint list?

I want to be able to create metrics on information in documents without duplicating the data in the document in a column of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 2007, it's possible to create custom document properties that can be displayed in SharePoint lists. You can also link a property to a bookmark in the document.

More info [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/create-custom-file-properties-HP005189755.aspx).